# Combine 2 variable with an array of html code in php

Tags: php, html

I have 2 variables in my php file and I want to combine it.

```
 // Option 1
 $x= array();
 $x[] = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
 $x[] = '<h1>World!</h1>';

  // Option 2
 $y= array();
 $y[] = '<h1>This is</h1>';
 $y[] = '<h1>Me!</h1>';

  //Combined Options
 $data = array();
 $data[] = $x;
 $data[] = $y;
```

If I return the $data

```
  return $data; // this returns array to string error
```

and if I return the $x

```
  return $x; // this is working
```

and if I return the $y

```
  return $y; // this is working
```

However I'm getting array to string conversion error. My goal is,

to combine *$x* and *$y*

Answer (score 2):

[Array Merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) PHP has a useful function to achieve this.

using it is as simple as this:

```php
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```